# IntelliJ constants.getProperty() autocomplete field

Tags: intellij-idea, properties

I have a large `constants.properties` file.

When reading properties from it with `constants.getProperty("PROPERTY_NAME")`, I often have to copy/paste the property names which is rather long.

I see that IntelliJ is able to detect when properties are used inside the code. Is it possible to have auto-completion of property names when I type the name in `getProperty()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, IntelliJ IDEA provides the completion for the Java Properties, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get the hints:

[image: properties completion]